# alamofire requests are not running asynchronously in ios application

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am trying to fire ~70 alamofire requests one after the other. I've noticed that they run sequentially and not in parallel. All the requests are submitted one after the other, but the responses are not generated in parallel. Is the IOS device throttling the requests? Am I missing anything? here is a sample of how i'm firing the request.

```
Alamofire.request(url , headers: headers).responseString { response in

do {
...
}
catch {
....
}

}
```

Comment: Need more code reference. How are you calling this block?

Comment: there are 7 procedures as of now let's say search1, search2, search3 ... search 7. each of these have alamofire.request(...) ... {} all the search procedures are called from viewdidLoad(). For every alamofire request in searchX, it launches 10 more alamofire requests. So, there are 70 in total. I noticed that they are not running in parallel.